# Delete tensorflow checkpoint and event files after training

Tags: python, tensorflow, shutil

After training and evaluating a custom tensorflow estimator, I would like to delete all the files that it saves - the checkpoint files, the event files, the eval folders, etc. - from within the same script. I am trying to do this by using shutil.rmtree on the directory that holds all the files; however, it keeps throwing this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users____\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\weakref.py", line 548, in **call**
    return info.func(*info.args, **(info.kwargs or {}))
  File "C:\Users____\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\tempfile.py", line 797, in _cleanup
    _shutil.rmtree(name)
  File "C:\Users____\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 494, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Users____\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Users____\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Users____\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Users____\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 393, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users____\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 391, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.rmdir(path)

OSError: [WinError 145] The directory is not empty: 'C:\Users\____\AppData\Local\Temp\4\tmpfuioqj79\search_1\fold_1\eval'

My understanding is that shutil.rmtree will remove the directory and all of its contents, and, when I use shutil.rmtree from a separate script after the script that creates and trains the models is finished, it works fine. Therefore, my I'm guessing that tensorflow is still using the files/directory. I cannot find anything in the estimator or saver documentation that would suggest I need to manually close something after training with the estimator implementation.

Anyone have any idea how to delete these files from the same script that performs the training and evaluation?

Edit: After looking through all the files that are being used by python processes, it looks like it's only the event files, not the checkpoint files, that are still in use.

Comment: You're right it may just be because the files are still in use. Is your code the clears the directory outside of your " `with session as sess:` "? Because if it is inside it those files will still be being used I'm fairly sure

Comment: @Recessive I'm using the estimator API, so I don't explicitly create the session. The call to train or evaluate handles that, so the session *should* be closed when I call shutil.rmtree. I'm starting to think it might be the Saver object that is still using the files.

Comment: Yeh, you should try `del saver`. Sorry, my tensor flow experience is only so much, just thought I'd give a suggestion in case it was right